# Convert multiple images to a pdf using Imagick

Tags: php, ajax, imagick

In the following code `$_POST['images']` is sent via Ajax and the code is the response. The problem is all images are in a single page of the created pdf file, I want each image to be in a separate page.

```
$images = $_POST['images'];


$pdf = new Imagick();
$pdf->setFormat('pdf');

foreach ($images as $dataURL) {
    $data = substr($dataURL, strpos($dataURL, ',') + 1);
    $image = base64_decode($data);

    $imagick = new Imagick();
    $imagick->readImageBlob($image);

    $pdf->addImage($imagick);
}

$pdf->resetIterator();
$pdf = $pdf->appendImages(true);
        
header('Content-Type: applicaton/pdf');
echo $pdf->getImagesBlob();
$pdf->destory();
```

Comment: Is it true that your asynchronous requests (file uploads of images by post) are multiple but distinctively separated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `Imagick::writeImages` takes two parameters file name and adjoin. If adjoin is set to true then each image is a separate page of the pdf [(documentation)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimages.php). Furthermore if we call this function and set adjoin to true then when the PDF is echoed each image is on a separated page. Using this we can have something like the following code:

```
$images = $_POST['images'];


$pdf = new Imagick();
$pdf->setFormat('pdf');

foreach ($images as $dataURL) {
    $data = substr($dataURL, strpos($dataURL, ',') + 1);
    $image = base64_decode($data);

    $imagick = new Imagick();
    $imagick->readImageBlob($image);

    $pdf->addImage($imagick);
}


// First we create a temporary file and write the pdf to it
$temp_name = '/tmp/output.pdf';
$pdf->writeImages($temp_name, true); // adjoin is true
unlink($temp_name); // Delete the temporary file

header('Content-Type: applicaton/pdf');
echo $pdf->getImagesBlob();
$pdf->destory();
```

Notice that we have removed

```
$pdf->resetIterator();
$pdf = $pdf->appendImages(true);
```

in the above code